# why does my gmail say "undisclosed recipients" in this case when I send email

Tags: postfix, smtp

I follow this method to send email through my localhost postfix server to gmail...

http://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/test-mail-through-telnet

but for some reason, gmail, says "undisclosed recipients"

Why is this?  I only sent the email to one user, myself.  Shouldn't it just report my email that received it?  do I have a postfix config setting wrong though I went mostly with the defaults.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: ouch, why all the hate, -4 on what seems a reasonable question and I am satisfied with the answer.....Just wanted to make sure it wasn't me or postfix was configured wrong....makes me more confident my postfix is setup correctly at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't follow that guide, basically.

If you need to email from the command line, you should use a command line mailer. Sending email is much more complex than it was in the old days; if you don't know what you're doing specifically you will run into problems.

Case in point, your question.